# jQuery Tabledit with multiselect drop-down

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery Tabledit and in which we have an option to use input box and Drop-drop but as of now, I need multiple selections in a single drop-down.

Please help us, if anyone has some solution regarding that. Help is highly appreciable.

Comment: They still have this as the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is what you expect,

```
$(function() {

  var $table = $('table');
  $table
    .Tabledit({
      columns: {
        identifier: [0, 'id'],
        hideIdentifier: true,
        editable: [
          [1, 'App Date'],
          [2, 'App Time'],
          [3, 'Service Type', '{"1": "@mdo", "2": "@fat", "3": "@twitter", "4": "@university"}',]
        ]
      }
    })
    .on('click', 'button:not(.tabledit-save-button)', function() {
      // prevent sorting while editing
      $table[0].isUpdating = $(this).closest('td').hasClass('tabledit-edit-mode');
    })
    .find('select[name="Service Type"]').attr('multiple', 'multiple')
    .on('click', 'button.tabledit-save-button', function() {
        // update tablesorter cache
      $table.trigger('update');
    })
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/856bzzeL/1274/)**